# Does infinite sum of almost surely 0 random variables converge to 0?

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series, probability-theory, convergence-divergence

Suppose we have an infinite sequence $X_i^{(n)}$ of random variables such that for each $i$, $X_i^{n} \overset{a.s.}{\to} 0$ as $n \to \infty$. With this in hand, which additional conditions need to hold (if any) to ensure that
$$\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}X_i^{n} \overset{a.s.}{\to} 0$$
as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: It looks like you need some condition for large values of $I$ knowing that $\sum_{i=1}^I X_i^n\to 0$, a.e. for all $I$.

Comment: You definitely need much stronger conditions than currently stated. If each sequence starts with $X_1^n = 1$ then each individual sequence can still converge to $0$ almost surely, while the sum can be greater than 1 infinitely often

Comment: @Xiaomi: Thanks, that's very insightful! Should have thought about that myself